# Why convert numbers to factors while model bulding

Tags: r, regression, data-science, data-analysis

I was following a tutorial on model building using logistic regression. 
In the tutorial, **columns having numeric data type and with levels 3, were converted into factors** using as.factor function. I wanted to know the reason for this conversion.

Comment: Which tutorial? How does the dataset looks like? Without more info we don't know why this has been done. But things encoded like gender in 0 1 2 tend to be set as factors.

Comment: Are you asking why categorical/nominal variables in a statistical model in R are (commonly) encoded as `factor`s? Or are you asking about the purpose of `factor`s in general? As to the former, see e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216099/linear-regression-r-need-to-convert-categorical-variables-to-factor-or-charac) and [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/coding-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-models/). As to the latter, I recommend any basic R tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

If vectors of class-"numeric" with a small number of unique values are left in that form, logistic regression, i.e. `glm( form, family="binomial", ...)`, will return a single coefficient. Generally, that is not what the data will support, so the authors of that tutorial are advising that these vectors be converted to factors so that the default handling of categorical values by the glm function will occur. It's possible that those authors already know for a fact that the underlying data-gathering process has encoded categorical data with numeric levels and the data input process was not "told" to process as categorical. That could have been done using the `colClasses` parameter to whichever `read.*` function was used.

The default handling of factors by most R regression routines uses the first level as part of the baseline `(Intercept)` estimate and estimates a coefficient for each of the other levels. If you had left that vector as numeric you would have gotten an estimate that could have been interpreted as the slope of an effect of an ordinal variable. The statistical tests associated with such an encoding of an ordinal relationship is often called a "linear test of trend" and is sometimes a useful result when the data situation in the "real world" can be interpreted as an ordinal relationship.